# vimtex and subfiles

Tags: subfiles

I'm sure this is extremely simple but I just can't figure it out.

I have the following directory structure:

```
main.tex
sections
|
    section1.tex
```

where main.tex contains

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
    \begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \subfile{sections/section1}
\end{document}
```

and

section1.tex looks like

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

My impression from the docs is that while editing `section1.tex`, by default `\ll` and then `\lv`  should result in `main.tex` being compiled and opened by my pdf viewer. However, instead I just get that `section1.tex` is being compiled and opened. Any advice on how to obtain the first behaviour?

Edit: Thanks @DaiBowen for giving the always salient advice of 'is your  up to date' - that's resolved it.

Comment: https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/155

Comment: @DaiBowen I had seen that issue, and it seem to me like in the resolution lervag makes a commit which should make things work as expected in my situation with no additional work, though I may be misunderstanding

Comment: Do things work if you place `section1.tex` in the same directory as `main.tex`?  Also you've tagged this question [tag:vim-latex] which is a different vim plugin, unless you are actually using [tag:vim-latex] you should retag the question.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything, nope. My bad on the tags - unfortunately I don't have a high enough score to change tags.

Comment: Have you checked that your vimtex is up-to-date?  Otherwise you could try opening an issue given your MWE seems quite simple.  From a get-things-working-quickly perspective you could try one of the other options mentioned in the link I gave earlier.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem solved by software updates.